# Wordpress 4.2 mce-views migration guide?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

With Wordpress 4.2 planned to be released [next week](https://make.wordpress.org/core/), I was wondering about the finalizing of the new [WP-views](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp-views) API. Apparently even the more simple examples of mce are [failing in 4.2](https://github.com/dtbaker/wordpress-mce-view-and-shortcode-editor/issues/3). I know that api is "experimental" but it hasn't had too much change in the last few releases. Has anyone started a migration guide for the developers registering their own mce-views?

Comment: Is [the hint to a post](http://generatewp.com/take-shortcodes-ultimate-level/) not good enough to play with this new view?

Comment: @bueltge That looks like a good overview for writing a plugin+preview in editor, but that is quite unrelated to my question as they are actually doing their own `editor.on('BeforeSetcontent'` and `editor.on('GetContent'` TinyMCE handlers, not the Wordpress-views `wp.mce.views.register` function.

Comment: Your comment is helpful for me to understand your goal.

Comment: Maybe this helps you - https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/tinymce-views-api-improvements/

Comment: @bueltge I think that's the answer, for now. Thanks